# How to migrate SVN repos from local Windows machine to Bitbucket?

Tags: git, svn, windows-7, bitbucket

I want to move an SVN repo to my Bitbucket account.

SVN is installed on a Linux server which I do not have access to. How can I do it from my local Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you access svn as a client (svn ls/checkout)? Then the most straightforward way would be to clone the svn repository with the help of git-svn, add your newly created bitbucket repository as a remote and push branches/tags that are still interesting there. This way you get history and branching in git.

Answer (score 0):

**Bitbucket hosts git and Mercurial repositories, so you need a git/Mercurial client, like TortoiseGIT.**

For detail information follow this link
[TortoiseGIT](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/)